# Process and make client side validation outside the initial form

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to process and make client side validation through a button not existing in the initial form.

Form A:

```
<h:form id="formA">
<p:messages closable="true"/>
<p:inputText  required="true" value="#{testBean.name}" requiredMessage="This field is required"/>
<p:inputText  required="true" value="#{testBean.age}" requiredMessage="This field is required"/>
</h:form>
```

Form B:

```
<h:form id="formB">
<p:commandButton  value="Save" process=":formA @this" action="#{testBean.save}" update=":formA"   />
</h:form>
```

The formA is not processed, and no client side validation is made. How can I achieve this please ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: did you add primefaces context param in web.xml?

Comment: I resolved the issue. I posted the answer below. Thanks anyway for interest and time. have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve my problem using remoteCommand. For those who have the same issue, below is the solution :

Form A:

```
<h:form id="formA">
<p:messages closable="true"/>
<p:inputText  required="true" value="#{testBean.name}" requiredMessage="This field is required"/>
<p:inputText  required="true" value="#{testBean.age}" requiredMessage="This field is required"/>
<p:remoteCommand name="processFormUser" process="@form" update="formA" action="#{testBean.save}"/>
</h:form>
```

Form B:

```
<h:form id="formB">
<p:commandButton  value="Save" onclick="processFormUser();"  />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<p:commandButton  value="Save" onclick="javascript:processFormUser(); return false;"  />
```